# Reading large files for a simulation (Java crashes with out of heap space)

Tags: java, performance, io

For a school assignment, I need to create a Simulation for memory accesses. First I need to read 1 or more trace files. Each contains memory addresses for each access. Example:

```
0 F001CBAD
2 EEECA89F
0 EBC17910
...
```

Where the first integer indicates a read/write etc. then the hex memory address follows. With this data, I am supposed to run a simulation. So the idea I had was parse these data into an `ArrayList<Trace>` (for now I am using Java) with trace being a simple class containing the memory address and the access type (just a String and an integer). After which I plan to loop through these array lists to process them.

The problem is even at parsing, it running out of heap space. Each trace file is ~200MB. I have up  to 8. Meaning minimum of ~1.6 GB of data I am trying to "cache"? What baffles me is I am only parsing 1 file and java is using 2GB according to my task manager ...

What is a better way of doing this?

A code snippet can be found at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33976/reading-large-files-in-java-getting-really-slow/33990?noredirect=1#33990)

Comment: To you need to have all the lines in memory to do the rest or would it be possible to process the line after being read, discarding your `Trace` object after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer I gave on codereview is the same](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33976/reading-large-files-in-java-getting-really-slow) one you should use here .....

But, because duplication appears to be OK, I'll duplicate the answer here.

---

The issue is almost certainly in the structure of your `Trace` class, and it's memory efficiency. You should ensure that the `instrType` and `hexAddress` are stored as memory efficient structures. The instrType appears to be an `int`, which is good, but just make sure that it is declared as an `int` in the Trace class.

The more likely problem is the size of the hexAddress String. You may not realise it but Strings are notorious for 'leaking' memory. In this case, you have a `line` and you think you are just getting the hexString from it... but in reality, the hexString contains the entire line.... yeah, really. For example, look at the following code:

```
public class SToken {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("99 bottles of beer");
        int instrType = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        String hexAddr = tokenizer.nextToken();
        System.out.println(instrType + hexAddr);
    }
}
```

Now, set a break-point in (I use eclipse) your IDE, and then run it, and you will see that hexAddr contains a char[] array for the entire line, and it has an offset of 3 and a count of 7.

Because of the way that String substring and other constructs work, they can consume huge amounts of memory for short strings... (in theory that memory is shared with other strings though). As a consequence, you are essentially storing the entire file in memory!!!!

At a minimum, you should change your code to:

```
hexAddr = new String(tokenizer.nextToken().toCharArray());
```

But even better would be:

```
long hexAddr = parseHexAddress(tokenizer.nextToken());
```

Comment: Didn't see it was a SE Site but even being one, you should provide more informations so the answer is more complete.

Comment: thanks works perfectly, the storing as long part. Looks like Strings are really leaking ... if Strings are leaky, shouldnt it be fixed in Java? Sounds like nothing is being done to fix this? In this case storing as long works, but what about other things, if I need to store relatively short strings, what do you recommend? In another language does it happen too? For example Python or JavaScript?

Comment: Strings only 'leak' when you do String-to-String operations where the new String has access to the internals of the old String. In most cases this works in your favour, consider `String line = "99 bottles f beer";` then `String ninenine = line.substring(0,2)` and `String bob=line.subString(3);` will take less space because they all share the same `char[]` array. The problem is when you throw away (and garbage-collect) the `line` and the `bob` variables, and you are left with an excessively large array behind the `ninenine`. variable.

Answer (score 1):

Like rolfl I answered your question in the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33976/reading-large-files-in-java-getting-really-slow).  The biggest issue, to me, is the reading everything into memory first and then processing.  You need to read a fixed amount, process that, and repeat until finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try use  class `java.nio.ByteBuffer` instead of `java.util.ArrayList<Trace>`. It should also reduce the memory usage.

```
class TraceList {

    private ByteBuffer buffer;

    public TraceList(){
        //allocate byte buffer
    }

    public void put(byte operationType, int addres) {
        //put data to byte buffer
    }

    public Trace get(int index) {
        //get data from byte buffer by index
        byte type = ...//read type
        int addres = ...//read addres
        return new Trace(type, addres)
    }

}
```